# Java - Round up 5.1 to 6

Tags: java, double, decimal

I am trying to round up 5.1 to the next whole number. I tried using math round, but it only rounds it to 6 if the value is 5.5 or over.

```
    int value = 51;
    double dataPerPage = 10;

    double amountOfPages = (double) value / dataPerPage;
    System.out.println(value + "/" + dataPerPage + " = " + amountOfPages);

    int sum = (int) Math.round(amountOfPages);
    System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
```

Comment: Use `Math.ceil`? Or, since it's integer math with positive numbers: `(value + dataPerPage - 1) / dataPerPage`.

Comment: Math.ceil did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.ceil() in this case

```
int sum = (int) Math.ceil(amountOfPages);
System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
```